# longPress decrement crosses 0

Tags: flutter, math, dart

In this code i try to reduce the number continuously upto i reach 0 through GestureDetector onTapDown and onTapUp function. This works well but **while pressing long it crosses the limit 0.**
In this code i try to reduce the number continuously upto i reach 0 through GestureDetector onTapDown and onTapUp function. This works well but **while pressing long it crosses the limit 0.**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Container1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Container1State createState() => _Container1State();
}

class _Container1State extends State<Container1> {
  int num = 20;
  Timer timer;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '$num',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  print('Down');
                  if (num >= 0) {
                    timer =
                        Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
                      setState(() {
                        num--;
                      });
                    });
                  }
                },
                onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    print('Up');
                    timer.cancel();
                  });
                },
                onTapCancel: () {
                  print('Cancel');
                  timer.cancel();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Icon(Icons.minimize),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  print('Down');
                  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
                    setState(() {
                      num++;
                    });
                  });
                },
                onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    print('Up');
                    timer.cancel();
                  });
                },
                onTapCancel: () {
                  print('Cancel');
                  timer.cancel();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not stopping the timer. You can do something like this

```dart
 Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        num--;
        if(num==0){
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the conditional.

> if (num > 0) {

You are currently saying that if it is 0 num- -. That will allow it to go negative.